# Vue.js | Store Pattern | Sharing Data Between (Sibling) Components

Tags: vue.js

I'm aware this question is at least triplication, but none of those answer my problem.

THIS IS A COMPLETE REPHRASE OF MY ORIGINAL QUERY.

I seek a presentation of Store Pattern which demonstrates all of the following:-

In general

- Components either with siblings or parent-child-grandchild-... relation can have access to the same data.
- They can mutate the data.
- They can mutually mutate the data (even mutating each other's
  mutation).
- Sequencing mutation order.
- Handling nested variables (raises reactivity issues).
- Single-file-components environment (correct exports / imports).
- Utilising Vue.observable

In particular

- I have a blueprint component and another component for building
  blocks.
- I want to create the output by using building blocks based on the
  blueprint's instructions.
- The blueprint has gaps for minimising human errors during raw data
  production and minimising network transfer.
- Therefore I also have a blueprint builder component which first
  completes the fetched raw blueprint.
- I want all the data handled by the Store.

Cheers

Comment: I am not sure what the actual issue is. Perhaps you need to take a look at the Vue Composition API ?

Comment: If the data is not mutated - why do not you use a computed property in each component to compute the value from store once and then cache it ? It might be difficult to simplify your real project but it is still difficult to understand what `exactly` are the issues you are facing ?

Comment: @IVOGELOV Because I need the data to be shared among components. With computed property, the data would be available for the component only which has the computed property. None of the others would know anything about what's going on in one of their sibling.

Comment: In the meantime I have managed to solve my problem. https://codesandbox.io/s/vuejs-store-pattern-f5pb5

Comment: The same solution in Nuxt.js. https://codesandbox.io/s/nuxtjs-store-pattern-rpwte
In Nuxt, for initial rendering, some components need to be in the layout folder.